# How connect neo4jRepository to local database? (java)

Tags: java, database, spring, neo4j, repository

I'm working on my project that works with neo4j database. I installed neo4j 
desktop v.1.0.21, and started database on bolt port 7687.
I have class for repository objects:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Feature {

@GraphId
private Long id;
private String nameOfFeature;

public Feature() {
}
```

Repository code:

```
@Repository
public interface FeatureRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Feature, Long> {
}
```

I can add items to database running query (same way i can read them):

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                params.put("name", sCurrentLine);
                session.run("CREATE (n:" + fileData.get(i) + " {nameOf" + fileData.get(i) + " : $name })", params);
            }
```

But i want to connect my ***FeatureRepository*** to my local database, and add/read objects through this repository class. Can i do this, if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [Spring Data Neo4J Quickstart](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/), you need to set up a configuration bean that points to your local database:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("org.neo4j.cineasts")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("org.neo4j.cineasts.repository")
public class PersistenceContext {

  @Bean
  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "org.neo4j.cineasts.domain");
  }

  @Bean
  public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
    return new Neo4jTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
    return new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder()
      .uri("bolt://localhost")
      .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when i tried to use it i had error: cannot resolve symbol 'Builder()'. And this didnt work for me. Tried import rest assured Builder() method (intellij proposed it to me) and it didnt help. Maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: Were you using the quickstart guide initially, and/or were you able to get that working by following the quickstart entirely? Without more information, it will be hard to pin down a root cause.

Comment: I'm working on my project that works with neo4j database, i'm not following quickstart guide.